# Why constructor is not called for the parent class while deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have 2 class X and Y.

```
public class Z extends Y implements Serializable{
    private String a;
    // getter and setter
}

public class Y{

    private int age;
    public Y() {

        this.age = 10;
    }
}
```

Now I serialize this  Y object. And then deserialize it.

```
age - 10  // constructor is called here.
a - myname
```

Now I have taken another case.

I have 2 class X and Y and Z.

```
public class X  implements Serializable{

    private String s;


public class Y extends X {
    private int age;    
    public Y() {

        this.age = 10;
    }
    }
public class Z extends Y implements Serializable{
    private String a;
}
```

Now here when I am deserializing Z object, the constructor is not getting executed.

And it is printing the values what I have set during my serialization.

Why is that?

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag Not a duplicate of that question in any way I can see. In that question the author already knows the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The no-args constructor of the nearest non-Serializable base class is called.

In the first case, that's Y().

In the second case, that's the constructor of the base class of X, which is Object().

Comment: +1 To the point answer..   Don't know why is it downvoted... Just want to add that in the later case of op question the parent constructor of `Y` is not called because `Y` is itself serializable since it is extending a serializable class `X`